# JSX skip if JSON field does not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am currently working with a JSON file from an API that does not add a key pair if the field is null. This is causing me grief when trying to iterate through the entire JSON file.

My code currently is

```
var ListOfItems = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var itemList = jsonFile.data.map(function(item)
        {
            return <Item key={item.__key}
                itemQuestion={item.question}
                itemQuestionAnswer={item.answer.answer}
                userName={item.user.name}
                staffName={item.staff.name}
                staffImage={item.staff.image_url} />
        });

        return (
            <div>
            <ul>{itemList}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Which gives an error for when item.answer.answer has no value.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by adding a condition to check, whether the item's answer type is not `undefined`. If it's not, proceed with returning a value, else don't return anything. This way, you only append another item if the condition has passed (I used shorthand for the condition).

```
var ListOfItems = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var itemList = jsonFile.data.map(function(item)
        {
            typoeof item.answer != 'undefined' && 
            return <Item  key={item.__key} itemQuestion={item.question}
                itemQuestionAnswer={item.answer.answer} userName={item.user.name}
                staffName={item.staff.name} staffImage={item.staff.image_url} />
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <ul>{itemList}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

If you always get `item.answer` but it's `answer` is either `undefined` or `null`, you can check for `item.answer.answer` in the code I've provided instead.

Comment: I'm surprised there is no simpler solution. When building views it is very convenient to have a simple way to traverse long object paths and ignore any missing fields silently.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big your list of items is, you could use the [builtin filter Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to first remove all the items you don't want, and then proceed to map through them. Keep in mind this will potentially go through your entire list twice.

A note about returning `undefined` from inside `map`. This will *not* prevent an item from getting returned. You will instead have an `undefined` item in your resulting array. The array will *not* be shorter.

Here's an example with `filter()`:

```js
var ListOfItems = React.createClass({
  renderItems: function() {
    return jsonFile.data
      .filter(function(item) {
        // This will return any item that has a truthy answer
        return item.answer && item.answer.answer;
      })
      .map(function(item) {
        return (
          <Item
            key={item.__key}
            itemQuestion={item.question}
            itemQuestionAnswer={item.answer.answer}
            userName={item.user.name}
            staffName={item.staff.name}
            staffImage={item.staff.image_url} />
        );
      });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.renderItems()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```